# wrong load value pdropdown

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

Suppose to have a dropdown where the all values are loaded from an assets. this is my json file:

```
 "students": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Allan"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Spago"
        }
    ],
    "students_select": {
        "id": "2"
    },
```

I call my service and it print me correct values:

```
this.fakeService.getDetail().subscribe((result) => {
        if (Utility.isNotNull(result)) {
          this.detail= result;

        }
      })
```

and in my html I do:

```
        <p-dropdown [options]="detail['students']" [(ngModel)]="detail['student_select']"  optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
```

the problem is that my values in dropdown are show correct but the only problem is that the value that must be show at the start is "`student_select`", but it show the first value "`id=1 and name=allan`". My api cannot be `"id:2 and  "name": "Spago""` because the correct way to return selected item is id. Anyone can help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your ngModel binding should also have the student name in it. Right now you only have student id in your `students_select`. In your ts file, try doing this.

```
selectedStudent = this.students.find(student => student.id === this.students_select.id);
```

then, change your HTML file like so

```
<p-dropdown [options]="detail['students']" [(ngModel)]="selectedStudent" optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>
```